# Is it possible to make API calls from azure web jobs?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-app-service-envrmnt

**My question is about make API request from azure web jobs.**

I have created azure Apps service for my web application (MVC C#).I have one API that need to run once in a day.I found one component in azure namely Azure Job which is paid one.Later I get to know about web jobs in my same Apps Services which not need to pay anything more, but I am not able to find anything that connects Web Jobs with API calls.Everywhere its mentioned about '.exe' files only.

Comment: What is your actual question? Answering the question in the topic: yes, it's possible. Since it's 'just' (C#) code, and it's 'just' calling an endpoint.

Comment: Azure App Service :to make API call inside web jobs.

Comment: it's possible. You can put your code which calls the API inside the web jobs(like a console project).

Comment: Ok thanks, I will create one console application that will call required API.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the first thing is that you could refer to this document to learn what is [webjob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs).

> WebJobs is a feature of Azure App Service that enables you to run a program or script in the same context as a web app, API app, or mobile app. There is no additional cost to use WebJobs.

As Ivan yang mentioend that you could create a console application or script and add call rest API code in it.

> Note : If your app runs **continuous or scheduled** WebJobs, enable **Always On** to ensure that the WebJobs run reliably. This feature is available only in the Basic, Standard, and Premium pricing tiers.

I recommand that you also could use the [Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tom Sun, company not interested to pay again for azure function.I will go with running script in web app.

Comment: WebApp and Azure function are billed according to service plan, if your webapp and  Azure function  are in the same service plan, there is no other cost.

Comment: Hi, were you able to implement this in app service? Can you share your approach?